# MVC - Displaying multiple class level validation error messages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, attributes

I have a viewmodel such that, on validation, I want to compare multiple fields. 
I have a custom attribute that takes the viewmodel and performs the required validation.
I am decorating the viewmodel class with the custom attribute [ValidateThisForm]

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ValidateThisForm : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        ViewModel _viewModel = value as ViewModel;

        if (_viewModel.TestOne == false && _viewModel.TestTwo == false)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Form Incomplete: Please correct";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I want to perform several "class level" validations. As a result, in my view, I can only display these errors in one place on the form:

```
<td class = "field-validation-error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(viewmodel => viewmodel)</td>
```

Is there a way that I can have multiple "class level" errors being displayed in different locations on the form?

Comment: Do you want change locations for others model properties? Such as: **@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => viewmodel.PropertyName)**

Comment: No, ideally I would like to update and display some of the the same models properties' error values from the class level validation code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your class currently looks something like this:

```
[ValidateThisForm]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool TestOne { get; set; }
    public bool TestTwo { get; set; }
}
```

If you have complex model-level validation you want to perform, where you can't simply annotate a single property, you can hook into the validation pipeline with [`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public bool TestOne { get; set; }
    public bool TestTwo { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    { 
      if (TestOne == false && TestTwo == false) 
      {
          yield return new ValidationResult("Form Incomplete: Please correct")
      }
    }
}
```

You can continue to `yield return` as many validation messages as you'd like. And you can display them all on the client with [`@Html.ValidationSummary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you'd like the message to appear alongside a particular control, the [`ValidationResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411880(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor takes an overload with the `memberNames` of the affected properties so you could change the `Validate` method like this:

```
if (TestOne == false && TestTwo == false) 
{
    yield return new ValidationResult("Form Incomplete Message", new[] {"TestOne"})
}
```

Then you can provide the validation message for that particular property with the [`ValidationMessageFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) HTML helper like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.TestOne )
```

For further reading, Scott Guthrie wrote about using `IValidatableObject` as part of his [blog post introducing new features in MVC3](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1) and had a follow up post with more detail on [class level validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3) shortly thereafter.